# Connection Oriented Transport Protocol

Tags: linux, networking

Does anyone have an idea about a software for Linux that uses COTP (ISO 8073) protocol ? note : software that runs COTP over TCP , doesn't matter what is the functionality of the software i just need to analyze the traffic of the protocol .

Answer (score 2):

ISO 8073 is commonly known-as TP4.  One possible *open* implementation for linux is the [ATN](http://atn.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/atn/) project on sourceforge.  Quoting their [`README`](http://atn.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/atn/README?revision=1.2&view=markup):

> WHAT IS TP4/CLNP?
>
> CLNP stands for connectionless network protocol, whereas TP4 stands for
>     transport protocol type 4, which is a connection-oriented transport protocol.
>     They are networking protocols defined respectively in the network layer and
>     the transport layer of the Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) framework of
>     the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). CLNP is
>     standardized in ISO/IEC 8473-1, whereas COTP (TP4) is standardized in
>     ISO/IEC 8073. As an analogy to the Internet networking protocol suite,
>     CLNP is just like IP, whereas TP4 is just like TCP. They are used as the
>     communication protocols in the digital data communication systems of the ATN
>     because the ATN follows the ISO OSI standards.
>
> WHY TP4/CLNP INSTEAD OF TCP/IP?
>
> Because the ICAO requires the use of communication protocols based on the ISO
>     OSI standards in the ATN as stated in Annex X to the Convention on
>     International Civil Aviation. Specifically, the second edition of Annex X
>     Volume III Part I, which is titled Digital Data Communication Systems, in
>     July 2007 states:
>
> ```
>  3.2.1 The aeronautical telecommunication network (ATN) comprises application
> entities and communication services which allow ground, air-to-ground and
> avionics data subnetworks to interoperate by adopting common interface
> services and protocols based on the International Organization for
> Standardization (ISO) open systems interconnection (OSI) reference model.
> ```
>
> WHAT IS THE OBJECTIVE OF THIS PROJECT?
>
> To provide the implementation of the ATN TP4/CLNP Networking Suite for the
>     Linux kernel in the spirit of the free software movement so that you are free
>     to:
>
> - run the program for any purpose (freedom 0)
> - study how the program works, and adapt it to your needs (freedom 1)
> - redistribute copies so you can help your neighbor (freedom 2)
> - improve the program, and release your improvements to the public, so that
>     the whole community benefits (freedom 3)

Note, someone might be quick to point out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350090/osi-tp4-implementation-for-linux-based-system) on SO; however, that project seems to require a password to see their SVN repo, and the blog is gone.

Comment: ill try it and get back to u, thanks.

Comment: i can't get it to compile although i did what they say in the readme .